# AOP advice breaks controllers

Tags: spring, aop, http-response-codes

I am writing a client-server application using Spring on backend and AngularJS on frontend. After writing quite a lot of Spring code I wanted to try AOP to extract logging code from controllers' methods. Unfortunately after adding aspects to my project controllers aren't working as they should.

To describe the simplest case, there's controller:

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
    @RequestMapping("/authenticate")
    public Principal authenticate(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

I expect the Principal to be injected here by Spring Security and sent to client - it all worked well, on the browser a response with 200 code could be seen and in the data there was authenticated Principal.

Then I introduced the following aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    private static final Logger logger =     LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(* correct.package.path.controllers.impl.*Controller.*(..))")
    public void withinControllers() {
    };

    @Pointcut("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public void requestMapped() {
    };

    @Before("withinControllers() && requestMapped()")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.debug("Entering {}", joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString());
    }
}
```

The advice is executed, the authenticate method is executed, but on the browser a 404 response is visible instead of correct one from before. Eclipse logs don't show any errors and I don't know where to go from there.

I've also noticed that when commenting out the @Before advice, leaving only @Pointcuts, it works well, just like before, but it's obviously useless as I need advices to work.

Can anyone explain what's the reason for such behaviour and how can I fix that?

Regards,
imralav

Comment: When using AOP on `@Controller`s make sure you are forcing class based proxies else your application will break. Instead of using AOP for the web I suggest using a filter/handlerinterceptor instead.